I have a set of words I would like to exclude, and I want to check if each new word entered is contained wholly within another. How would I do this?
So I am currently making a word game, and I want to have it so that the user cannot enter a word that is wholly contained within another word (e.g. 'set' in 'subset'), however my current code:
noWord = False
for _word in used_words:
    if set(word).issubset(set(_word)):
        noWord = True
if noWord == False:
    # Calculate score for the word

makes it so that it doesn't matter what order the letters are in (e.g. playing 'pitch' would prevent you from playing 'chip') which is a feature I do not want. How would I go about doing this efficiently.
I tried searching the _word variable as a list and checking if each set of letters from that list matches the word variable, but that was incredibly inefficient.
e.g.
wordAsAList == list(_word)
# All words have to be 3 letters or more in my game
for v in range(len(wordAsAList) - 2):
    for i in range(len(wordAsAList)):
        if len(wordAsAList) - v - 3 >= i:
            if ("".join(wordAsAList[i:(len(wordAsAList) - v)])) == word:
                noWord = True

Beyond that I have little to no clue how to solve the problem / make the code above more efficient. (Also I know I shouldn't use range(len(list)), but I still do anyway)
Thanks in advance :)

The find method of the string type will probably be a good choice.

As a simple solution, I would probably remember (in a set) not only all used words, but also all possible fragments of all used words. Then it is trivial and fast to check. Just calculate how many words you expect and how much memory that will require.

msg = 'Hello'
new_msg = 'llo'
print(new_msg in msg)

This question is similar to: How do I get a substring of a string in Python?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@16171413 I am not asking how to get a substring of a string, in fact in my code I literally implement the use of substrings - Line 6 in the second code snippet.

That is what set does. set create a set (that is a collection without any order, whose purpose is to verify what belongs to it, what is included in it. Well, sets. Like in math).
To build a set, you call set with another collection of things. Like S=set([3, 1, 2]) is the set containing numbers 1, 2 and 3. Then set([1,3]).issubset(S) is True, since set {1,3} is included in set {1,2,3}
And when you call set with something that is not a collection, you get an error. set(1) raises an error.
Now, here, you called set with a string. That you consider to be a "atomic" value. So, you may think that it should have raised an error. But a string is a collection: a collection of chars. So S=set("hello") is really the set containing {'h', 'e', 'l', 'o'} (in any order). And T=set("lol") is also a set, {'o','l'} (I show them in random orders, since, like in maths, there is no order).
So T.issubset(S) is True here. Because all elements of T are also elements of S.
Now, that was "why". As for "how" it is very simple:
"set" in "subset"

is True.
And this time, in the sense you expect it to be: because string "set" is included in string "subset".
To check if a word is part of any word of a list, you can
L=["subset", "hello", "world"] # example list of words
any("set" in x for x in L) # True, because "set" is substring of one of the words of L
any("lol" in x for x in L) # False, because "lol" is substring of no word x of L

